# ifconfig not displaying NIC's and also no wired Ethernet connection

Tags: gentoo, ifconfig, rc

After rebooting, my network interface card (renamed from `eth0` to `enp0s25`) is not displayed with the command ifconfig, only in `ifconfig -a`. Also ping -c 4 google.com only yields unknown host. In my `/etc/resolv.conf` file, the name server is set to my router which deals with all of the DNS bs. I checked to see if net.enp0s25 is installed at runlevel which it was. I was trying out MATE and dbus/xdm threw alot of error messages after the reboot. Also `ping 8.8.8.8` yield network unreachable. Trying to set the interface to up through  `ifconfig up enp0s25` yields `enp0s25`: Host Name lookup Failure.

Comment: I enabled logging in rc, and it throws many errors at localmount failing to start in which it lists"cannot start net.enp0s25 as localmount would not start"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had usb filesystems listed in my /etc/fstab file and localmount could not find these since they were no longer plugged in. I had like a 4 month uptime, so I am sure I forgot about my edits to my /etc/fstab file. However, I still cannot connect to the internet, but hey I fixed the ifconfig issue.

Comment: I had to redo my /etc/resolv.conf file for some reason, After I fixed fstab, it regenerated my resolv file so that it had no nameservers. One more reboot and ping worked with 0% packet loss.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the predictable name via the kernel boot option: `net.ifnames=0` to have your eth0, or up you interface via:

```
cd /etc/init.d/ && \
ln -s net.lo net.enp0s25 && \
/etc/init.d/net.enp0s25 restart
```

Or manually enable:

```
ifconfig up enp0s25 192.168.0.150
```

(replace 192.168.0 by your network prefix)